# Nothing related to python works without sudo

Tags: python, setuptools

I am in very terrible situation because I ran few commands without completely understanding their effects.

I am not able to use pip, not able to install anything with pip without prefixing sudo to it. I am able to install it with sudo.
Here are few error traces

```
LAP-044:Downloads pratik$ pip install requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

This is because of setuptools. So I tried to reinstall setup tools. I am getting this error.

```
LAP-044:Downloads pratik$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12059  100 12059    0     0  12823      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12815
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 415, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 411, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 327, in download_setuptools
  File "<stdin>", line 347, in _resolve_version
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

The same setuptools installation is successful if I run it with python3. Can anyone tell me what exactly is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to run `pip` in a virtual environment? If you aren't it will try to install to a machine-wide location, for which you would normally need root privileges.

Comment: You also may want to check the output of `which pip` and `which python`.

Comment: @WayneWerner :  I get /usr/local/bin/python
and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip for which python and which pip.

Comment: Looks like your `pip` and your `python` don't match up. Is there a `pip` in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: yes. There is pip in /usr/local/bin along with pip2 and pip2.7 also

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you creating a virtual environment where you can install everything without using sudo. This is the cleanest way of working in Python.

Obviously if you Python executable is in a directory that needs root permission, you will need the sudo

Once it's create, you should activate it:

```
$ source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

And then you can install packages using pip:

```
$ (myvirtualenv) pip install [somepackage]
```

Depending on the Python version that you are using in your virtualenv, you might have to install pip. But it usually comes with Python 2.7 which is default Python version

[virtualenv docs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)